# How to get numeric value of input if it has text and compare to if function?

Tags: jquery, text, numeric

I need the next function to work:

```
if(!currentvalue >= $(this).val()) {
    $(this).val('It is free now')
  }
```

The thing is when the value is numeric only - it works fine. But I also need to add the text like ",000 usd" to this value. So after that the IF function is not working. Is it possible to make it work and how?

[The link on example on codepen.](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/RWExLO)

Comment: Regardless of the number/text thing, I'm fairly certain you don't mean that condition to be `!currentvalue >= $(this).val()`. Perhaps `currentvalue < $(this).val()`. The `!` applies to `currentvalue`, not the entire expression following it, so you'll end up either comparing `true` or `false` to the value from the input.

Comment: I guess the example is not your code, because is working fine. Your problem is that you are reading directly the value of the inputs, and not parse anything. You need to store the number values and paint the text values. It's easy but we need to view more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out what I changed in your [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zveEGa) ->

```
$('.number').each(function() {
  var curval = $(this).data('summary');
  var newval = parseInt(curval - ui.value * 0.08);
  if(!curval >= (newval * 1000)) {
    $(this).val('It is free now')
  }   else {
     $(this).val(newval + ",000" + " usd");
  } 
});
```

You had the Value in numeric format before the If so why not evaluate before that rather than reverting to what you had before to check.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of thoughts,

first if you're simply trying to ascertain the numeric value of a textbox you can use

`parseInt($(this).val()) >= someInt`

second, if you're trying to get the value of a textbox minus "some text" you can use

```
var value = $(this).val();
var intVal = value.substring(value.indexOf("sometext", value.length);
```